# Decomposition of Two related Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Given the filtration $\{\cal{F_t}\}_{t\geq 0}$, there are two Brownian Motions $W_t, \hat W_t$, such that the correlation between $W_t$ and $\hat W_t$ is constant $0<\rho<1$. I try to write 
$$\hat W_t~=~\rho W_t + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} B_t$$

where $$B_t\doteq \frac{\hat{W_t} - \rho W_t}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}.$$

Can we prove that in this decomposition, $B_t$ is a Brownain motion that independent of $W_t$?

I can prove the correlation between $W_t$ and $B_t$ is $0$, so can we conclude they are independent? One way is to prove $(W_t,B_t)$ are Gaussian, can we prove this assertion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are $W$ and $\hat W$ jointly Gaussian?

Comment: not necessarily. If there are jointly Gaussian, then we can prove there are independent, since the correlation is 0.

Comment: Since $W_t, B_t$ are martingales, can we utilize this fact, plus the fact that the correlation is $0$, to conclude that they are indeed independent?